# How do I customize the appearance of Chrome 120

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome 120 just dropped, and in the `chrome://whats-new/` page, it explains that Chrome now has a new look, and how to customize the look of Chrome:

[image]

> ### Customize Chrome, your way
>
> Chrome has a new look that comes with more options in Customize Chrome. You can try out new expressive colors and themes, and also choose between light and dark mode.
>
> 1. Open a **New tab ➕**
> 2. At the bottom of the page, click **Customize Chrome ️**.
> 3. Explore the new options under **Appearance**.

In my case i want customize the appearnce because the new taller tab-strip, new taller address bar, new taller bookmarks bar, eats away another inch of viewable page-reading space (i.e. it has turned into Edge)

So i need to customer it back to how it was.

#### Research Effort

1. Open a **New Tab ➕** on my desktop browser:

   [image]
2. At the bottom of the page click...*nothing*...because there is nothing at the bottom of the page:

[image]

So it seems like that **What's New** page was written by GPT 2.0.

What are the **correct** instructions on how to customize the appearance of Chrome? Obviously not just color themes and background; but actually customize the "new" appearance to customize it to look like the old appearance.

Or at least get my reading space back.

### Bonus Chatter

How do we fix:

[image]

It's almost as if tech companies are forgetting that desktop applications are not web-sites, and we don't want our applications to have a WebUI. HTML has never produced a good user-interface, and there are interfaces for a desktop that are so much better than trying to mimic a WebUI.

Comment: There is no going back, unless you wish to lock yourself to Chrome 119 forever.

Comment: `nothing at the bottom of the page` ... it depends on the `default search engine`

Comment: Re "HTML has never produced a good user-interface": *Any* user interface can be implemented with HTML. There are some good ones. But I totally agree that most web design trends in recent years are crap.

Comment: @root I've never seen a listview in HTML. Multiple resizable columns, horizontal scrolling if the columns go off the right edge, cut off header and cell text replaced with..., vertical scrollbar when the number of items exeeds the ListView's client size, header remains visible as you scroll down, column re-ordering, virtual mode so i can add 100,000 at a time. Not even Microsoft's new WebUI contains a ListView.

Comment: @Ian Much of what you're describing is implemented in HTML (including CSS and JavaScript, which can be embedded in HTML) in Google Sheets, [Tabulator](https://tabulator.info/), and various other web apps. All of it can be implemented.

Comment: Your post has 585 views and counting. By being ultra long, it wastes readers' time and energy. I had suggested an edit, but someone rejected it.

Comment: @root And my first look at Tabulator and i see [First] [Prev] [1] [2] [3] [Next] [Last].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the problem is that Chromium is trying to make Chrome look like a web-site, or *WebUI* in the lingo.

The solution is to go back—and turn off WebUI:

- `chrome://flags/#chrome-webui-refresh-2023`
- `chrome://flags/#customize-chrome-side-panel` *(as of March 2024)*

[image]

After a restart of Chrome, it is turned back into a Windows application:

[image]

## Bonus Reading

There are other options in Chrome as part of the ***"2023 Refresh"***:

- **Chrome Refresh 2023** (`chrome://flags/#chrome-refresh-2023`)

  Enables the new desktop design. – Mac, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, Fuchsia, Lacros
- **Chrome Refresh 2023 New Tab Button** (`chrome://flags/#chrome-refresh-2023-ntb`)

  Enables the variations of the new tab button for chrome refresh 2023. – Mac, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, Fuchsia, Lacros
- **Realbox Chrome Refresh 2023** (`chrome://flags/#ntp-realbox-cr23-all`)

  Enables all NTP Realbox Chrome Refresh features – Mac, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, Fuchsia, Lacros
- **Chrome Refresh 2023 Top Chrome Font Style** (`chrome://flags/#chrome-refresh-2023-top-chrome-font`)

  Enables the bolder version of font styles for Top Chrome components. – Mac, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, Fuchsia, Lacros

But **WebUI** is the only one that turns Chrome into a dripping bag of hot garbage.

Comment: I removed your “Bonus Chatter” nonsense that reads: “Please don't comment if you don't know the answer and have nothing useful to contribute.” Please do not insult the members of this community.

Comment: As of March 2024 you also need to disable `chrome://flags/#customize-chrome-side-panel` to go back to the old UI.

Comment: @KeithJohnson Thank you for that. Chrome updated a week ago and i went on a jihad; disabling everything until it fixed it. Then i didn't want to go back and figure out exactly which one fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for the update!  It worked for me!