# How to revert Chrome to the old add to bookmark UI

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Is there a way to revert the add-to-bookmark UI back to the earlier version that allows you to choose which folder the new bookmark will go immediately without having to click further?

That is in addition to being able to immediately change name, edit URL, or remove erroneous addition.

I tried setting the `#chrome-refresh-2023` flag to disabled but it doesn't do it.

(Memory is vague here. Disabling the flag either never worked in terms of the particular UI feature or worked for a while until a recent Chrome update.)

### Old and wanted:

[image]

### New and unwanted:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I customize the appearance of Chrome 120](https://superuser.com/questions/1821955/how-do-i-customize-the-appearance-of-chrome-120)

Comment: @Ramhound: No. I tried the suggested flags in the linked answer because you suggested so -- despite of the linked question and answer not having given any reference to the question being asked here, which is the question you voted to close. And those flags do **not** change the behavior of bookmark addition asked for in this question. I can appreciate the effort you put into your other question. Nonetheless, I really struggle to see how you saw a connection to close this question.

Comment: This question isn’t closed. I don’t appreciate the tone of your response, you seem frustrated, by a single close vote. Furthermore, a [different question](https://superuser.com/questions/1836740/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-ui-elements-of-chrome?noredirect=1&lq=1) that was about the bookmarks, indicated the new flag did solve the problem. I won’t be returning to this question and will ignore all pings.

Answer (score 2):

The closest solution i've found so far is using extension ["Bookmark Plus"](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/bookmark-plus/kcipcflegclplnkpbijedkhgljodgfcp) and assigning shortcut key `ctrl+D` to it.

An alternative option without extensions is changing your habit and use the new shortcut key: `ctrl+D+D+D` which gives you the old looking.

However there are still issues that did not exist with the old UI.

1. `Alt+R` to remove a bookmark does not work, even with the built-in popup, after activating the editing mode, in the new version.
2. the extension mentioned above adds the new entry to the top of an existing folder, which is the opposite of the built-in ui behavior.

P.S. the flag you were looking for was "Simplified Bookmark Save Flow" -- it was available directly until M118, and through unexpiring flags until M121, and entirely removed in M122.

Answer (score 0):

To modify Chrome's bookmarks interface requires an extension.

Below are some extensions and their interfaces:

- [booky.io](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/bookyio-extension/pmcpkkipiedakcaolhnbijibndfemckf)

  [image]
- [Bookmark Sidebar](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/bookmark-sidebar/jdbnofccmhefkmjbkkdkfiicjkgofkdh)

  [image]
- [Bookmarks Extension for Google](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/bookmarks-extension-for-g/ngncegjbgnfpifehgmcjgniphmcjjipc)

  [image]
- [raindrop.io](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/raindropio/ldgfbffkinooeloadekpmfoklnobpien)

  [image]
- [Save to Pocket](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/niloccemoadcdkdjlinkgdfekeahmflj)
  This has a different concept than the others.