# Is there a way to change the default UI elements of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface

Every so often, Google will release a UI refresh for their Chrome browser that will introduce new features and settings.  In most cases though, it's possible to rollback those changes using the `chrome://flags/` page.  Sometimes though the flags do not seem to work and/or you need to enable/disable a combination of flags to get a previous visual style back.

Today happens to be one of those days.

The newest chrome update to 123.0.6312.59 (March 26, 2024) seems to have broken the flag though.

As a comparison, this is what it looks like previously:
[image: 3 pinned tabs on the left with four standard tabs on the right, no padding between them]

And this is after the refresh:

[image: Tab organizer on the left, four pinned tabs, and three new tabs with excessive padding between each tab]

(Apologizes for the inconsistent images, had to pull the previous version from a machine that had not updated yet.)

Assuming that the #chrome-refresh-2023 flag is broken or removed permanently, is there any other way to change the UI settings of Google Chrome like the padding between tabs or even the default dropdown box?

Comment: I assume your trying to disable the refresh rather then allowing it to happen. The only interface changes are those controlled by UI options or internal flags. As with all Chromium browsers those flags are eventually retired once the feature is finished or promoted into a production state.

Comment: If the problem are the bookmarks icons, on my Chrome they are all correct. If this is caused by some of your flags, you might try to reinstall Chrome to get a fresh version (save your profile folder and export bookmarks).

Comment: @harrymc In this case, it's not the bookmark icons but the padding between the tabs at the very top.  I'm trying to get the original view back with small to no padding as I don't use Chrome full screen.

Comment: @Ramhound that's correct.  the chrome-refresh-2023 flags still exist but does not seem to return the UI back to the previous state when they're set to "disabled".  That is how I've managed to get that compact view for longer

Comment: Try to set `chrome://flags/#customize-chrome-side-panel` to disabled, if it's still working.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you! and Thank you Ramhound as well!  I tired the steps in that answer before making this question, but the latest update (to the original answer) to disable chrome://flags/#customize-chrome-side-panel fixed it!